# What is the purpose of declaring a variable with the format variable : class type = in python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming in general. I would like to know why this symbol is being used in a few codes. What I mean is, what is the purpose of this way of declaring a variable? Is it useful?

For example let's say I define

```
say_hello1 = "hello everybody"
```

I could also define the same variable using:

```
say_hello2 : str = "hello everybody"
```

Or ..

```
say_hello3 : float = "hello everybody" # I know this is not a float variable, I'm doing it on purpose
```

Each variable (say_hello1, say_hello2 and say_hello3 ) will be the same type (string). So what is the purpose of this way of declaring variables? Is it just to say that the variable will be a specific type? Or does it change anything else (i.e the efficency of the code)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just an annotation for readability.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was that but I was not pretty confident about my thoughts hahah. Thank yo uso much for the comment!

Comment: Its python's Jump The Shark moment. It gives type hints and IDE's use it to give more information when programming. But really, if you read the docs of the functions you call, you don't need them.

Comment: Check out the PEP for this feature, it explains the rationale behind adding this feature.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: Annotations have helped PyCharm save me from stupid. mistakes on so many occasions!  Calling a function with the wrong argument type.  Returning the wrong type from a function.  All of these are easy to accidentally get wrong and easy for PyCharm to catch if you give it the right information.

Comment: @tdelaney you don't need them? You should not be merging in any code that doesn't pass mypy checks, unless you really don't care about other developers, or letting bugs through to production.

Comment: @Dan - My point exactly. A minor feature useful for type hints in IDEs has now become required for check in of code?! And its supposed to substitute for good quality testing and an understanding of the APIs that we use? If you've got a good development methodology, these type hints should solve 0 problems. Maybe you write your code a bit faster - not in my experience, though. They are mostly just useless liter in the code base. Doc strings are more than sufficient to solve the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I strongly disagree with you. Static type checking is not a minor feature and is also why these annotations were introduced, not as a minor feature for your IDE. It greatly speeds up development, especially when using third party functions. This "litter" greatly increases your code readability, helps you find bad interfaces etc etc.

Comment: "And its supposed to substitute for good quality testing" - substitute? No. It is part of good quality testing. Otherwise are you including defensive if statements in every function you write to raise TypeErrors? Otherwise a developer could end up getting an error 10 internal functions deep in the call stack when you could have avoided all that by telling them to input a string and not a int for example. For the same reason you want tests so your code doesn't break in production, you want static type checking so you don't have to find your bugs at run time.

Comment: @Dan - You clearly want a statically typed language and there are plenty of them out there. Frequently they are faster than python to boot. Python is not actually statically typed so all we've done is add a complication for little benefit other than what `pydoc` gives you. Code isn't checked in without a code review, and the code review includes the accompanying tests. A developer who hasn't taken the time to understand the API being called is in need of some mentoring from the reviewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows what variable you are expecting, which makes your code a lot easier to read and understand. It can also help with linters and other third party tools. Python itself won’t look at it afaik.

Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Specifically with `mypy` - it lets you catch a lot of bugs before you run your code. Also, it lets your IDE highlight errors.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not a strongly-typed language. The `variable : type` is just for readability, does not declare strongly typed variables. Later you can change the value, even in another type.

Comment: "is just for readability" - I strongly disagree with this. It allows you to use a static type checker (i.e. mypy) to catch bugs before you run your code. If you do this then "Later you can change the value, even in another type" will throw an error which will make your code much safer.

Answer (score 1):

Type hints were introduced in [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/). The goal is to allow *additional tools* to do static linting based on the acceptable types for a variables. This is included for example in PyCharm, and is used by [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/).

But anyway, Python is a dynamic language, and the interpretor just ignores those declared type hints.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the type is pretty obvious so it is not very helpful but assume that you have a base class `BaseClass` that some other classes inherit `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`, then:

```
a: SubClassA = SubClassA()  # not very useful
a: BaseClass = SubClassA()  # indicates that you expect a given interface, no necessarily SubClassA

### another dev can safely replace code later on
a: BaseClassA = SubClassB()
```